# How do we take any array value without initialization in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, array-initialization

Like with initialization:
We take like:

```
 Dim a() as integer = {1,2,4,6}
```

And if i want to print the array list it will be 1 , 2 ,4,6 as output
But how can i take any value i.e n value to print n values as output.

Comment: If you need a different array, then: `Dim n As Integer = 3` followed by `Dim b() As Integer = a.Take(n).ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your best bet will be to add *n* elements from the array to a second array and print that instead:

```
Dim a() as integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}

Dim b as new list(of integer)
' Where n is the total number of elements you want to print.
For counter As integer = 0 To n
    b.Add(a(counter))
Next

PrintItems(b)
```

I haven't worked in VB for nearly 10 years so apologies if my code isn't 100% correct.

Comment: What is the use of the List here? You could just, e.g.,: `for each v as Integer In a.Skip(1).Take(3) Console.WriteLine(v) next` to print out elements from index 1 to 3. BTW, to initialize a List with the elements of `a`, just `Dim b As New List(Of Integer)(a)`

Comment: I used a list here because I'm actually an idiot lol I forgot how to create an empty array... I usually use lists in my code anyway

Comment: Will wait on feedback from OP first... in the meantime please don't report my comments D: I'm so close to 10k although it's taken a decade to get this far lol